# Can the server use a file from a client without uploading it to the server? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, client-side, server-side

I was wondering, at the moment, the client uploads a file to a directory on the server where the server can then use the file (csv file) to update a SQL database.

Is that the only way the server can use that file? For it to first be uploaded to the server? Or can you use that file without uploading it to a directory of the server?

(using visual studio 2012, C# and asp.net)

Code update---

asp Uploading the file. (I know the code can be cleaner an written better, but my testing code is never clean)

```
                //Uplod file to the server
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(serverUploadDir + FileUpload1.FileName);

                //Use the Uploaded File to update the sql table
                dbConn.UploadCSVToSql(serverUploadDir + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

The UploadCSVToSql

```
  public void UploadCSVToSql(string filepath)
        {
            //string filepath = "C:\\Copy of ABI Employee List.csv";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] value = line.Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;
            foreach (string dc in value)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
            bc.DestinationTableName = "MainDump";
            bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
            conn.Open();
            bc.WriteToServer(dt);
            bc.Close();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Mayby you can try to parse the file in your C# program and do the SQL in C# also...

Comment: You can just read the data of the file and do what you need to do using a streamreader() (or similar). You can also read a file on a LAN (obviously) with the correct permissions (which means it doesn't actually live on the server).

Comment: You don't need to upload it to a directory, you can post it back to the server and store it in memory

Comment: it depends on the program's logic on the server side. if it's read from specific folder to get the csv file. then you should upload it first to the server

Comment: I've updated my code example. It all happens once the user clicks the upload button on the asp upload control. I first upload it then use the file that has been uploaded. It works, but if there is a better way to do it (or a way I SHOULD do it, then I would like to know)

Comment: Also because this method runs into security issues when the client does not have access to the specific folder on the server.

Comment: Once you access the FileUpload1 object, it's already on the server, it's not nessesary to save it to a folder... unless of course you want to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how you would get a file from the client to the server without uploading it, but you don't need to store it to a folder. If you use the

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuMyUpload" runat="server" />
```

control. you can get the data in a stream and store it in memory.

```
    if (!fuMyUpload.HasFile)
    {
         lblWarning.Text = "No file Selected";
         return;
    }

    var csvData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fuCircuitCsv.FileBytes);

    using (var reader = new StringReader(csvData))
    {
          var headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
                 var fields = line.Split(',');
          }
    }
```

Comment: ah, that's almost exactly what I wanted.. I'm trying this now, will let you know how it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a background job running on the server which monitors the folder for any CSV file, then it needs to be uploaded to the server. If that is not the case, then you should be able to process the file in C# only and perform database update.