# Reading Client excel file using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to read and excel file from the client using EPPlus without uploading it to the server or using a file upload control. The file will be located in the same location all the time.

Is this possible? When looking it to it, I only found solutions which read from the server or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955325/opening-a-client-side-excel-file-using-epplus) which uses a file upload control which I do not want.

If it is not possible using EPPlus, what other method would you suggest to read an excel file in ASP.net C# from a client location (network drive available to all users) without sending it to the server and using the file upload control.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: So iv added this active x script on my aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var readExcel = function() {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\qt98512\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx");
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value;
        var data2 = excel_sheet.Cells(0, 0).Value;
        return data;

    } 

</script>
```

Assuming that is correct, how do I access the returned data in my c# page? I have a button running the script like this:

```
protected void testbuttonExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "script", "readExcel();", true);
        }
```

Comment: To achieve what you want you need some piece of software on the client itself with enough permission to do what you want - That is only possible with some ActiveX control/JavaApplet

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Does not look like there is a nice way :( May have to scrap this idea.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the case, you have to upload the file into server in order to really use it. However, if you only need to use the file for once, you may consider to put the file into memory and stream your file.

[This show how to store the file data to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605138/can-the-server-use-a-file-from-a-client-without-uploading-it-to-the-server-asp)

[This case are using excel with EPP too. Check if it suit your needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777185/can-i-download-an-excel-file-made-from-a-memory-stream-off-an-asp-net-page?rq=1)